# asp.net mvc Linq going through 1 million records(proccess time)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

Ok in this scenario if if i bring all the records at once from this query

```
var pages=_db.Pages;
```

and then i will process according to some scenario

```
pages.Where(m => m.int_PostStatusId == 2) 

pages.Where(m => m.int_PostStatusId == 3)  and so on
```

is it really saving some processing time? or not (what really to do ?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to know that this almost certainly does *not* bring "all the records at once":

```
var pages = _db.Pages;
```

Assuming this is LINQ to SQL or something similar, this just creates a *query* - it doesn't actually fetch anything from the database.

When you use `pages.Where(...)` that creates a new query - again, it doesn't actually fetch anything from the database until you start reading from the query (e.g. by calling `ToList`). As such, it's very hard to tell how to help you optimize your code - we don't know what you're doing.

Are you trying to do anything with *all* the pages, or only with a subset? If you're trying group by PostStatusId, I suggest you do that explicitly rather than by fetching with lots of different filters.

Comment: @mazhar: That's not *nearly* enough information to help us give you advice.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `pages` is a database aware linq query provider then the most efficient using
way would be to write a single query to get all the data you want:

```
// Create the query
var pages = 
      _db.Pages.Where(p => p.int_PostStatusId >= 2 && p.int_PostStatusId <= 100);

// Execute the query
foreach(var page in pages)
    ProcessPage(page);
```

This would generate SQL a bit like this:

```
select *
from PAGE_TABLE
where PostStatusId >=2 and PostStatusId <= 100
```